# Webpack throws error with Emscripten: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, module, webassembly, emscripten

I'm encountering errors in importing a javascript file into a vue.js component:

This is the content of /components sub-folder:

```
/startingV/src/components$ ls -lah
total 132K
drwxr-xr-x 2 marco marco 4,0K dic 26 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 marco marco 4,0K dic 26 09:32 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco  441 nov  2  2016 Counter.vue
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco  441 dic 21 15:13 FormValidation.vue
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco 100K dic 26 10:38 js_plumbing.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco 9,3K dic 26 10:38 js_plumbing.wasm
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco  473 dic 26 11:14 Result.vue
```

When compiling:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/js_plumbing.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/marco/cpp/WebAssemblyinAction
/Appendix_B/B.1_ccall/startingV/src/components'
```

this is the Result.vue file:

```
template>
    <p button @click="callAdd">Add!</p>
</template>

<script>
    import * as js_plumbing from './js_plumbing'
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          result: null
        }
      },
      methods: {
        callAdd() {
          const result = Module.ccall('js_plumbing.Add',
              'number',
              ['number', 'number'],
              [1, 2]);
          console.log('Result: ${result}');
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

The js_plumbing.js and the js_plumbing.wasm files have been generated through this command :

```
emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap']
```

where add.c is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

// If this is an Emscripten (WebAssembly) build then...
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
  #include <emscripten.h>
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { // So that the C++ compiler does not rename our function names
#endif

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int Add(int value1, int value2) 
{
  return (value1 + value2); 
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This is the link I took some info about how to generate the .js and .wasm files:
https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-ccall-cwrap

Complete error message in the command line when doing npn run dev :

```
(base) marco@marco-U36SG:~/cpp/WebAssemblyinAction/Appendix_B 
/B.1_ccall/startingV$ npm run dev

> myproject@1.0.0 dev /home/marco/cpp/WebAssemblyinAction/Appendix_B 
/B.1_ccall/startingV
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 12bee4de7abfde1cbc5d
Version: webpack 4.41.3
Time: 6707ms
Built at: 12/26/2019 12:37:07 PM
   Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
build.js  2.18 MiB    main  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = build.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080   
(webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js 52 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js] 319 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http:
//localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080  
4.29 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-
server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-
server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js]   
(webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.89 KiB {main} 
[built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-
server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] 
(webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js] 
(webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {main}   
[built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync 
nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js
 1.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 75 
bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-
apply-result.js 1.27 KiB {main} [built]
[./src/main.js] 134 bytes {main} [built]
    + 34 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/components/js_plumbing.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/marco 
/cpp/WebAssemblyinAction/Appendix_B/B.1_ccall/startingV
/src/components'
 @ ./src/components/js_plumbing.js 88:26-39
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader
/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/Result.vue
 @ ./src/components/Result.vue
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader
/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
```

How to solve it?
Marco

Comment: What's inside `js_plumbing.js` file?

Comment: Hi @Piyush ! I updated my question with the content of js_plumbing.js file

Comment: What did you use to compile that returns the error?

Comment: @BumsikKim I compiled the add.c file with this command: emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap']

Comment: Oh, I was asking the very first compile command that complains there is no 'fs' module, not emcc command. I guess emcc command does not make the error, right?

Comment: @BumsikKim I updated my question with the complete error message in the command line when doing npn run dev

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### TLDR;

There are two solutions:

1. Add `-s ENVIRONMENT='web'` in your emcc command, so try `emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap'] -s ENVIRONMENT='web'`

or

2. Add `"node": { "fs": "empty" }` field in your `webpack.config.js`. I don't know how to do it in zero-config way though.

### Why

Emscripten's emcc command produces both `.js` and `.wasm` files. The `.js` file is not only a wrapper of the `.wasm` but also provides a C/C++ runtime for the web, and more importantly in the question, a generic loader for the `.wasm` file.

The `.js` file's loader is very comprehensive that covers node, web, web worker, and [D8 JS shell](https://v8.dev/docs/d8) by default. This often make problems with bundlers such as Webpack because the bundlers try to resolve all modules in the source code, including `require('fs')` which is used for loading `.wasm` file in the nodejs environment, and the bundler produces error if any module is not available for the web environment.

One way to avoid the problem is that to use [`ENVIRONMENT`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/79523944931f526c4b1c2a92e1a826475c987a2b/src/settings.js#L540) flag in `emcc` command. This will remove some problematic codes such as `require('fs')`.

Another way is to let Webpack ignore `fs` module by adding `"node": { "fs": "empty" }` in the webpack configuration.

Comment: I tried both ways: both with ENVIRONMENT='web' and module.exports = {
  node: {
    'fs': 'empty'
  },
in webpack.config.js and it works fine. Thank you very much for your kind excellent explanation

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation! For Next.js + Webpack 4/5 I combined option 2 with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68098547/2578205
I think I had a bit more to disable since I was using pthreads:
```
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      fs: false,
      process: false,
      path: false,
      perf_hooks: false,
      buffer: false,
      worker_threads: false,
    };
    return config;
  },
```