# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in Next.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, fs

Unable to identify what's happening in my next.js app. As **fs** is a default file system module of nodejs. It is giving the error of **module not found**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try a fresh `npm install` after removing the `node_modules` folder

Comment: As @AjitZero said that would be the issue. You can also remove `package-lock.json` and run `npm cache clean` and then `npm install`

Comment: I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and then npm cache clean and npm install...but still the same error appears.

Comment: You cant use fs module in browser its a nodejs module.

Comment: Indeed, definitely check you are NOT using it in the browser. This caught me out recently... I forgot and started importing it in the browser. It took me a few days to fix the issue :/

Comment: Ensure that you're using Next.js' `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, `getInitialProps`, etc. inside a Next page, not a normal component. I was doing this and it caught me out for a sec.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If you use `fs`, be sure it's only within [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) or [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#getserversideprops-with-typescript). (anything includes server-side rendering).

You may also need to create a `next.config.js` file with the following content to get the client bundle to build:

For `webpack4`

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    if (!isServer) {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
    }

    return config
  }
}
```

For `webpack5`

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };

    return config;
  },
};
```

Note: for other modules such as `path`, you can add multiple arguments such as

```js
{
  fs: false,
  path: false
}
```

Comment: Gold answer! Just that I also had to add `path: false` after `fs: false`.

Comment: As the question is asked about `fs` only, @JusticeBringer. I might not be able to add in the code but let me add it as a note.

Comment: Still not work for `next@^12.3.1`.

Comment: Is it possible to use fs if it's only in functions that are only called by getStaticProps? It doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @Jeffmagma yes, if you import `fs` and are not using it inside `getStaticPaths` or `getStaticProps` (and other server-only default methods) , then you will see the error from the OP.

Answer (score 57):

I spent hours on this and the solution is also here on Stackoverflow but on different issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67478653/17562602

Hereby I asked for MOD permission to reshare this, since this issue is the first one to show up on Google and probably more and more people stumble would upon the same problem as I am, so I'll try to saved them some sweats

Soo, You need to add this in your `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {

  // Can be safely removed in newer versions of Next.js
  future: {

    // by default, if you customize webpack config, they switch back to version 4.
    // Looks like backward compatibility approach.
    webpack5: true,   
  },

  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.fallback = {

      // if you miss it, all the other options in fallback, specified
      // by next.js will be dropped.
      ...config.resolve.fallback,  

      fs: false, // the solution
    };
    
    return config;
  },
};
```

It works like a charm for me.

**Edit**: For newer versions of Next.JS, the option `future.webpack5` has been replaced by `webpack5`, which defaults to `true`. Since we are using Webpack 5 for this solution, this option can be safely removed.
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/future-webpack5-moved-to-webpack5#possible-ways-to-fix-it

Answer (score 42):

**Minimal reproducible example**

A clean minimal example will be beneficial to Webpack beginners since auto splitting based on usage is so mind-blowingly magic.

Working hello world baseline:

pages/index.js

```
// Client + server code.

export default function IndexPage(props) {
  return <div>{props.msg}</div>
}

// Server-only code.

export function getStaticProps() {
  return { props: { msg: 'hello world' } }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Run with:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

Now let's add a dummy `require('fs')` to blow things up:

```
// Client + server code.

export default function IndexPage(props) {
  return <div>{props.msg}</div>
}

// Server-only code.

const fs = require('fs')

export function getStaticProps() {
  return { props: { msg: 'hello world' } }
}
```

fails with:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

which is not too surprising, since there was no way for Next.js to know that that `fs` was server only, and we wouldn't want it to just ignore random require errors, right? Next.js only knows that for `getStaticProps` because that's a hardcoded Next.js function name.

OK, so let's inform Next.js by using `fs` inside `getStaticProps`, the following works again:

```
// Client + server code.

export default function IndexPage(props) {
  return <div>{props.msg}</div>
}

// Server-only code.

const fs = require('fs')

export function getStaticProps() {
  fs
  return { props: { msg: 'hello world' } }
}
```

Mind equals blown. So we understand that any mention of `fs` inside of the body of `getStaticProps`, even an useless one like the above, makes Next.js/Webpack understand that it is going to be server-only.

Things would work the same for `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticPaths`.

**Higher order components (HOCs) have to be in their own files**

Now, the way that we factor out `IndexPage` and `getStaticProps` across different but similar pages is to use HOCs, which are just functions that return other functions.

HOCs will normally be put outside of `pages/` and then required from multiple locations, but when you are about to factor things out to generalize, you might be tempted to put them directly in the `pages/` file temporarily, something like:

```
// Client + server code.

import Link from 'next/link'

export function makeIndexPage(isIndex) {
  return (props) => {
    return <>
      <Link href={isIndex ? '/index' : '/notindex'}>
        <a>{isIndex ? 'index' : 'notindex'}</a>
      </Link>
      <div>{props.fs}</div>
      <div>{props.isBlue}</div>
    </>
  }
}

export default makeIndexPage(true)

// Server-only code.

const fs = require('fs')

export function makeGetStaticProps(isBlue) {
  return () => {
    return { props: {
      fs: Object.keys(fs).join(' '),
      isBlue,
    } }
  }
}

export const getStaticProps = makeGetStaticProps(true)
```

but if you do this you will be saddened to see:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

So we understand another thing: the `fs` usage has to be directly inside the `getStaticProps` function body, Webpack can't catch it in subfunctions.

The only way to solve this is to have a separate file for the backend-only stuff as in:

pages/index.js

```
// Client + server code.

import { makeIndexPage } from "../front"

export default makeIndexPage(true)

// Server-only code.

import { makeGetStaticProps } from "../back"

export const getStaticProps = makeGetStaticProps(true)
```

pages/notindex.js

```
// Client + server code.

import { makeIndexPage } from "../front"

export default makeIndexPage(false)

// Server-only code.

import { makeGetStaticProps } from "../back"

export const getStaticProps = makeGetStaticProps(false)
```

front.js

```
// Client + server code.

import Link from 'next/link'

export function makeIndexPage(isIndex) {
  return (props) => {
    console.error('page');
    return <>
      <Link href={isIndex ? '/notindex' : '/'}>
        <a>{isIndex ? 'notindex' : 'index'}</a>
      </Link>
      <div>{props.fs}</div>
      <div>{props.isBlue}</div>
    </>
  }
}
```

back.js

```
// Server-only code.

const fs = require('fs')

export function makeGetStaticProps(isBlue) {
  return () => {
    return { props: {
      fs: Object.keys(fs).join(' '),
      isBlue,
    } }
  }
}
```

Webpack must see that name `makeGetStaticProps` getting assigned to `getStaticProps`, so it decides that the entire  `back` file is server-only.

Note that it does not work if you try to merge `back.js` and `front.js` into a single file, probably because when you do `export default makeIndexPage(true)` webpack necessarily tries to pull the entire `front.js` file into the frontend, which includes the fs, so it fails.

This leads to a natural (and basically almost mandatory) split of library files between:

- `front.js` and `front/*`: front-end + backend files. These are safe for the frontend. And the backend can do whatever the frontend can do (we are doing SSR right?) so those are also usable from the backend.

  Perhaps this is the idea behind the conventional "components" folder in many official examples. But that is a bad name, because that folder should not only contain components, but also any library non-component helpers/constants that will be used from the frontend.
- `back.js` and `back/*` (or alternatively anything outside of `front/*`): backend only files. These can only be used by the backend, importing them on frontend will lead to the error

Comment: Sir, you are my hero. This minimal reproduction example was what I needed to understand the problem. Honestly, is quite annoying to see that the code elimination is that dumb and that it does not traverse the code any further than plain string matching.

Answer (score 20):

While this error requires a bit more reasoning than most errors you'll encounter, it happens for a straightforward reason.

### Why this happens

Next.js, unlike many frameworks allows you to import **server-only** (Node.js APIs that don't work in a browser) code into your **page files**.  When Next.js builds your project, it removes **server only** code from your client-side bundle by checking **which code exists inside one any of the following built-in methods** (code splitting):

- `getServerSideProps`
- `getStaticProps`
- `getStaticPaths`

*Side note: there is a [demo app](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/) that visualizes how this works.*

The `Module not found: can't resolve 'xyz'` error happens **when you try to use server only code outside of these methods**.

#### Error example 1 - basic

To reproduce this error, let's start with a **working** simple Next.js page file.

**WORKING file**

```
/** THIS FILE WORKS FINE! */

import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

import fs from "fs"; // our server-only import

type Props = {
  doesFileExist: boolean;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const fileExists = fs.existsSync("/some-file"); 

  return {
    props: {
      doesFileExist: fileExists,
    },
  };
};

const ExamplePage = ({ doesFileExist }: Props) => {
  return <div>File exists?: {doesFileExist ? "Yes" : "No"}</div>;
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

Now, let's reproduce the error by moving our `fs.existsSync` method *outside* of `getServerSideProps`.  The difference is subtle, but the code below will throw our dreaded `Module not found` error.

**ERROR file**

```
import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import fs from "fs";

type Props = {
  doesFileExist: boolean;
};

/** ERROR!! - Module not found: can't resolve 'fs' */
const fileExists = fs.existsSync("/some-file");

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      doesFileExist: fileExists,
    },
  };
};

const ExamplePage = ({ doesFileExist }: Props) => {
  return <div>File exists?: {doesFileExist ? "Yes" : "No"}</div>;
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

#### Error example 2 - realistic

The most common (and confusing) occurrence of this error happens when you are using modules that contain multiple *types* of code (client-side + server-side).

Let's say I have the following module called `file-utils.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs'

// This code only works server-side
export function getFileExistence(filepath: string) {
  return fs.existsSync(filepath)
}

// This code works fine on both the server AND the client
export function formatResult(fileExistsResult: boolean) {
  return fileExistsResult ? 'Yes, file exists' : 'No, file does not exist'
}
```

In this module, we have one server-only method and one "shared" method that *in theory* should work client-side (but as we'll see, theory isn't perfect).

Now, let's try incorporating this into our Next.js page file.

```
/** ERROR!! */

import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

import { getFileExistence, formatResult } from './file-utils.ts'

type Props = {
  doesFileExist: boolean;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      doesFileExist: getFileExistence('/some-file')
    },
  };
};

const ExamplePage = ({ doesFileExist }: Props) => {

  // ERROR!!!
  return <div>File exists?: {formatResult(doesFileExist)}</div>;
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

As you can see, we get an error here because when we attempt to use `formatResult` client-side, our module **still has to import the server-side code**.

To fix this, we need to split our modules up into two categories:

1. Server only
2. Shared code (client or server)

```
// file-utils.ts

import fs from 'fs'

// This code (and entire file) only works server-side
export function getFileExistence(filepath: string) {
  return fs.existsSync(filepath)
}
```

```
// file-format-utils.ts

// This code works fine on both the server AND the client
export function formatResult(fileExistsResult: boolean) {
  return fileExistsResult ? 'Yes, file exists' : 'No, file does not exist'
}
```

Now, we can create a **WORKING** page file:

```
/** WORKING! */

import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

import { getFileExistence } from './file-utils.ts' // server only
import { formatResult } from './file-format-utils.ts' // shared

type Props = {
  doesFileExist: boolean;
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      doesFileExist: getFileExistence('/some-file')
    },
  };
};

const ExamplePage = ({ doesFileExist }: Props) => {
  return <div>File exists?: {formatResult(doesFileExist)}</div>;
};

export default ExamplePage;
```

### Solutions

There are 2 ways to solve this:

1. The "correct" way
2. The "just get it working" way

#### The "Correct" way

The best way to solve this error is to make sure that you *understand* why it is happening (above) and **make sure you are only using server-side code inside `getStaticPaths`, `getStaticProps`, or `getServerSideProps` and NOWHERE else**.

And remember, if you import a module that contains *both* server-side and client-side code, you cannot use *any* of the imports from that module client-side (revisit example #2 above).

#### The "Just get it working" way

As others have suggested, you can alter your `next.config.js` to *ignore* certain modules at build-time.  This means that when Next.js attempts to split your page file between *server only* and *shared* code, it will not try to polyfill Node.js APIs that fail to build client-side.

In this case, you just need:

```js
/** next.config.js - with Webpack v5.x */
module.exports = {

  ... other settings ... 

  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    
    // If client-side, don't polyfill `fs`
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        fs: false,
      };
    }

    return config;
  },

};
```

##### Drawbacks of this approach

As shown in the [resolve.fallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback) section of the Webpack documentation, the primary reason for this config option is because as-of Webpack `v5.x`, core Node.js modules are no longer polyfilled by default.  Therefore, the main purpose for this option is to provide a way for you to define *which* polyfill you want to use.

When you pass `false` as an option, this means, "do not include a polyfill".

While this works, it can be fragile and require ongoing maintenance to include any new modules that you introduce to your project.  Unless you are converting an existing project / supporting legacy code, it is best to go for option #1 above as it promotes better module organization according to how Next.js actually splits the code under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for this. In my case I had `file-utils.ts` and `file-format-utils.ts` exported from a single `index.ts` file. Next I guess combined the server-side and client-side code into one inoperable blob. Removing the `export` for `file-format-utils.ts` in `index.ts` ultimately fixed it.

Comment: Your first assumption is incorrect. It is not just when you try to use server only code outside of the blessed methods, the compiler is so dumb that it can only remove code from the direct file you are in, and if you try to refactor things in any way (for example, having a HOC) it will fail to understand which code to remove. You don't need to execute such code, as soon as you require it you are doomed.

Comment: Well said, @Zach!

Comment: Thank you for your effort to write such a good answer, you saved my day.

Comment: how to use it with next-auth and node mailer  these packages always cause such issue.

Answer (score 15):

`fs`,`path` or other node native modules can be used only inside server-side code, like "getServerSide" functions. If you try to use it in client you get error even  you just console.log it.. That console.log should run inside server-side functions as well.

When you import "fs" and use it in server-side, next.js is clever enough to see that you use it in server-side so it wont add that import into the client bundle

One of the packages that I used was giving me this error, I fixed this with

```
module.exports = {
 
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback.fs = false
    }

    return config
  },
  
}
```

but this was throwing warning on terminal:

```
"Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which

 dependencies cannot be statically extracted"
```

Then I tried to load the node module on the browser. I copied the "min.js" of the node module from the node_modules and placed in "public/js/myPackage.js" and load it with Script

```
export default function BaseLayout({children}) {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        // this in public folder
        src="/js/myPackage.js"
        // this means this script will be loaded first
        strategy="beforeInteractive"
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

This package was attached to `window` object and in node_modules source code's index.js:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  window.TruffleContract = contract;
}
```

So I could access to this script as `window.TruffleContract`. BUt this was not an efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

If trying to use fs-extra in Next.js, this worked for me

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false, path: false, stream: false, constants: false };
    return config;

  }
}
```

Comment: End with `return config;`

Answer (score 3):

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  webpack5: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      fs: false,
      net: false,
      dns: false,
      child_process: false,
      tls: false,
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

This code fixed my problem and I want to share.Add this code to your next.config file.i'm using

> webpack5

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in my NextJS app because I was missing `export` in

```
export function getStaticProps()
```

Comment: I had a related error, but instead I misspelled getServerSideProps so I was utilizing the fs module client side. An easy mistake to make!

Answer (score 2):

in Next 13 an 14 you need to add 'use server' at the top of your page:

```
'use server'
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

const Test = async () => {

    const file = await fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '../../data/gamelist.json', 'utf8');
    const data = JSON.parse(file);
...
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me clearing the cache
npm cache clean -f

and then updating the node version to the latest stable release(14.17.0) worked

Comment: This worked for me. Voted

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error appeared while refactoring the auth flow of a Next.js page. The cause was some an unused imports that I had not yet removed.

Previously I made the page a protected route like so:

```
export async function getServerSideProps ({ query, req, res }) {
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/signin',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }
//... rest of server-side logic
}
```

Whilst refactoring, I read up on NextAuth [useSession](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession). Based on what I read there, I was able to change the implementation such that I simply needed to add
`MyComponent.auth = true` to make a page protected. I then deleted the aforementioned code block inside of `getServerSideProps`. However, I had not yet deleted the two imports used by said code block:

```
import { unstable_getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
import { authOptions } from 'pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]'
```

I believe the second of those two imports was causing the problem. So the summary is that in addition to all of the great answers above, it could also be an unused import.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error can be because you have imported something but not mastered it anywhere. This worked for me. I reviewed my code and removed the unused dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the module you are trying to implement is not supposed to run in a browser. I.e. it's server-side only.

Comment: @asma Firstly there is nothing like a "verified answer" here on StackOverflow. Secondly, the OP had accepted this answer and not that of ArjunKava because the latter was posted 6 months after they had asked the question, and hadn't cared much to accept a better one since. Also, this is a perfectly valid reasoning. Server only packages can and do cause such issues if used in client-side code. PS: after the outdated answers update this answer is no longer pinned to top, so it shouldn't be an issue because this was the answer that helped OP _when_ they needed, and hence is the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the old version of the node.js installed. It requires node.js version 14 and higher. The solution was to go to the node.js web page, download the latest version and just install it. And then re-run the project. All worked!

Comment: It did not work for me when i tried building with node 14.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to use babel.

For me this worked:

#add a `.babelrc` file to the root of the project and **define presets and plugins**
*(in my case, I had some issues with the macros of babel, so I defined them)*

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": ["macros"]
}
```

after that shut down your server and run it again

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue. My problem was that I was importing types that I had declared in a `types.d.ts` file.

I was importing it like this, thanks to the autofill provided by VSCode.

```
import {CUSTOM_TYPE} from './types'
```

It should have been like this:

```
import {CUSTOM_TYPE} from './types.d'
```

In my case, I think the `.d` was unnecessary so I ended up removing it entirely and renamed my file to `types.ts`.

Weird enough, it was being imported directly into `index.tsx` without issues, but any helper files/functions inside the `src` directory would give me errors.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in a NextJS application because I had defined a new helper function directly below getServerSideProps(), but had not yet called that function inside getServerSideProps().

I'm not sure why this created a problem, but it did.  I could only get it to work by either calling that function, removing it, or commenting it out.

Comment: This may provide some insight on why you got the issue: [Webpack with Next.js bundles file it is not supposed to in client bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748083/1870780). If you have unused imports Next.js can't figure out the import is only meant to be used on the server, so it'll be included on the client bundle - causing the `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'` error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `fs` in the `pages` directory, since next.js suppose that files in `pages` directory are running in browser environment.

You could put the util file which uses `fs` to other directory such as `/core`

Then `require` the util in `getStaticProps` which runs in node.js environment.

```
// /pages/myPage/index.tsx
import View from './view';
export default View;

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const util = require('core/some-util-uses-fs').default; // getStaticProps runs in nodes
  const data = await util.getDataFromDisk();
  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: _"next.js suppose that files in pages directory are running in browser environment"_ - That's not entirely correct. You _can_ use `fs` (or any Node.js library) inside `pages` as long as it's only used in server-side code (inside `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`). Next.js [automatically eliminates](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/) server-side code from the client-side bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Many needlessly long answers here, here's the **TLDR** solution, it only works Server side (why see other answers). (Answer Without App/src dir - using Pages)

Statically generated page:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const { promises: { readFile } } = fs;

  const csharp = (await readFile('./data/c#.txt')).toString();

  return {
    props: {
      csharp,
    }
  }
}
```

or Server side generated page:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const { promises: { readFile } } = fs;

  const csharp = (await readFile('./data/c#.txt')).toString();

  return {
    props: {
      csharp,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I started receiving this error today when deploying to vercel, adding the following to my package.json seemed to work

`"browser": { "fs": false },`