# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' - NextJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm trying to use node-jsencrypt with NextJS (tsx):

index.tsx

```
import JSEncrypt from 'node-jsencrypt';
```

package.json

```
"node-jsencrypt": "^1.0.0"
```

Log

> error - ./node_modules/node-jsencrypt/index.js:2:0
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Notes:
I didn't find the `'webpack.config.js'` file, as I saw in some topics.

Comment: if you are trying to use it in the browser side, it won’t work, because it is a nodejs library.

Comment: you need an isomorphic library, but for fs I think that it does not exists, [this link explain about building an isomorphic package](https://hackernoon.com/building-isomorphic-javascript-packages-1ba1c7e558c5)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application

Answer (score 20):

Ok, I played around with this issue & I think I have what cover all possible combinations. In the [repo](https://github.com/marcin-wosinek/webpack-next-js/branches) you can find working examples. There are 3 possible approaches, and the right one will depend on what's already in your project - details that were unspecified in the original question.

1. Solution while using webpack 5 [`next.config.js`](https://github.com/marcin-wosinek/webpack-next-js/blob/webpack-5/next.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true, // by default, if you customize webpack config, they switch back to version 4. 
      // Looks like backward compatibility approach.
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback, // if you miss it, all the other options in fallback, specified
        // by next.js will be dropped. Doesn't make much sense, but how it is
      fs: false, // the solution
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

2. Solution while using webpack 4 - [`next.config.js`](https://github.com/marcin-wosinek/webpack-next-js/blob/webpack-4/next.config.js)

```
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) { // we depend on nextjs switching to webpack 4 by default. Probably they will 
    // change this behavior at some future major version.
    config.node = {
      fs: "empty", // webpack4 era solution 
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

3. You could consider using other library. According to [`node-jsencrypt readme`](https://github.com/ArnaudValensi/node-jsencrypt#readme) they are node port of [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt), and here I assume you try to build for browser. The node library got stuck at version 1, while the original library is already at version 3. As I checked in [the last commit on main](https://github.com/marcin-wosinek/webpack-next-js/commit/182c56e5eb9ac75adbab4a1943a52f6303c13ff4), if you use this library, it's building just fine without any issues.

*Original, nextjs unaware answer:*

Since version 5, webpack doesn't include polyfiles for node libraries. In your case, you most likely need to add `resolve.fallback.fs: false` to your webpack config.

More about this option- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback
It mentioned in v4 to v6 migration guide, if this is your case:
https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/

Comment: Second solution does not work on me: "configuration[0].node has an unknown property 'fs'" First one seem to work.

Comment: First slution is nice.Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

In the next.config.js file add the code below

```
build: {
extend(config, {}) {
    config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using next.config.js, do you know how to add this?

Comment: I mean next.config.js not nuxt.config.js

Comment: ok, just add next.config.js at then root directory. then add  module.exports = {build: {
extend(config, {}) {
    config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
    }
}}

Comment: Unfortunately this seemed to have no effect for me, even after quitting and re-running `yarn dev`.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue when integrating sendGrid. However, I solved by adding a **webpack** property in **next.config.js** file like below:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      fallback: {
        fs: false,
      },
    };
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```