# NextJs with LangChain - Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: node.js, next.js, langchain

I need some help with a NextJS App with Langchain. I also use the Vercel AI SDK and got an API Route `/api/chat`. Here is how my content looks like:

```
import { config } from "dotenv";

config();

import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { FaissStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/faiss";
import { AIChatMessage, HumanChatMessage } from "langchain/schema";

export const runtime = "edge";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const { messages } = await req.json();

  const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings();
  const vectorStore = await FaissStore.load("./", embeddings); # creates error

 ... # Rest
```

the load function of `FassStore` uses the fs module under the hood. It results in `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`.

NextJS API routes should be able to use `fs`, see here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32236

I also came across this: [Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' - NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67478532/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-nextjs) . This seems not to be a viable option.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here or how to fix that? Thank you :-)

Comment: Edge runtime doesn't have access to the file system - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/edge#unsupported-apis

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue?