# Can't resolve 'fs' when importing OneSignal

Tags: import, next.js, yarnpkg, onesignal

I have added OneSignal to my NextJS app using `yarn add onesignal-node` and then imported it in my _app.js file like this `import * as OneSignal from 'onesignal-node'` but I get

```
error - ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Can someone help. I can't even do a basic import without an error.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a Node.js library on client-side code, which won't work as the code will run on the browser. Make sure you only use `onesignal-node` in server-only code, like `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps` or API routes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in Next.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post demonstrating how to add push notifications into your NextJS project.

https://onesignal.com/blog/how-to-integrate-onesignal-into-a-next-app/

Keep in mind that what you are doing is not going to work because you are trying to import a Node package that is only for the server-side.

If you want to learn more about our developers' community, take a look at this link https://onesignal.com/onesignal-developers and join us!