# Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs/promises' (next-sitemap)

Tags: next.js, sitemap

**next-config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'ru'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['fakestoreapi.com'],
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    const newConfig = { ...config };

    if (!isServer) {
      newConfig.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
    }
    return newConfig;
  },
};
```

Next sitemap version - `"next-sitemap": "^2.1.15",`

**next-sitemap.js**

```
/** @type {import('next-sitemap').IConfig} */

module.exports = {
  siteUrl: 'https://box.hedgefun.net/',
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
};
```

Above you can see as I try to use `next-sitemap` for creating sitemap , I've found solution to add `fs` to `next-config.js` file, for `webpack 5` . But it show me next issue . How can I fix it ?

```
node -v
v14.16.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same issue in Node v12.22.12.

I have solved issue by updating the Node version to **v14.18.0**

So please update the Node version to **v14.18.0** or more

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to solve this problem by simply increasing the node version:

```
v14.17.0` -> `v16.14.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by upgrading my node version to v16.17.0. Also, take a look at this solution.
[1]: [Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in Next.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application)