# Updating server-side data from the client in NextJs tutorial blog

Tags: reactjs, next.js, persistence, server-side-rendering

The NextJs tutorial sets up a blog that uses [pre-rendering via static generation](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/with-data) to read data dependencies (blog posts, in this case) from markdown files, sending this data as props to the page. Very neat!

I went to build upon this by adding the ability to edit the markdown on the page. After implementing said editability I aimed to persist the changes, but I reached a [blocking error message saying 'fs' can't be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application). It then hit me that I am trying to execute some server-side code (saving markdown to files) from the client.

What options do I have to save markdown from the client?

Comment: Move the logic to access and manipulate the file to an API route (server-side), then make a request from the client to that same API route to make the changes.

Comment: @juliomalves this can be done within the same nextjs app? so it acts as a front-end (consumes post crud api) and back-end (exposes post crud api) as the same time?

Comment: Yes, it can indeed.