# i have install fs module but still i got the error that module is not foud

Tags: node.js, next.js

i have install fs module but still i got the error that module is not foud
https://prnt.sc/J_kApm93R9SW

how to resolve this problem

Comment: look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application

Comment: Is this a script that runs in the front-end?  If so, there is no `fs` module in the browser.  The `fs` module only exists in nodejs and can only be used in scripts that run in nodejs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Answer (score 0):

Read the first comment.

TL;TR

Use `fs` somewhere in server-side code. [Use this tool](https://next-code-elimination.vercel.app/) to check generated client-side code. Copy your code and play around. fs should disappear if you use it in `getServerSideProps` and reappear, if you don't use it.