# Switching from getServerSideProps() to getStaticProps() generates module not found 'fs' at build time in NextJS

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, modulenotfounderror

I have a NextJS app in which I wanted to change some routes' SSR from getServerSideProps to getStaticProps. Doing so made the project unable to build, when it worked fine before:

```
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/package.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\nextjs_project\node_modules\@mapbox\node-pre-gyp\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/package.js
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
./Database.js
```

The code inside the function remained the same, I only changed the function call:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() { //Only change is I swapped getServerSideProps for getStaticProps.
  const Id = Id_value; //Id_value located in a file at rootlevel
  const Name = "Name";
  
  const [json_value] = await Promise.all([
    getStuffFromAPI(Id),
    //There was originally two funciton calls here, hence the Promise.all, haven't bother to rewrite yet.
  ]);
  return {
    props: {
      some_bool: false,
      some_string: JSON.stringify(json_value[0]),
      some_other_string: Name,
    },
  };
}
```

What could be causing this? fs is not used in this route at all. The internal API has one or two usages of it. But why would that eventually break it? As per the trace I check the Database.js, but fs is not used in there. Not sure how one debugs problems like this as it's my first time encoutering one.

**Next.js v12.3.1,
Node.js v18.16.1**

After googling and reading the forum I've tried the [webhook settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application) in next.config.js, without success.