# Next.js React Component won't allow HTML in "export default" function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

I've defined a Next.js (TypeScript/React) as follows:

```
'use client'
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { Uploader } from "uploader";
import { UploadButton } from "react-uploader";
import * as fs from 'fs';

const uploader = Uploader({
    apiKey: "free" // Get production API keys from Bytescale
  });
  
const options = { multi: true };

export default function Certificates() {
    return (
        <h1>Certificate Management</h1>
        <UploadButton uploader={uploader}
                  options={options}
                  onComplete={files => alert(files.map(x => fs.readFileSync(x.fileUrl, 'utf-8')).join("\n"))}>
        {({onClick}) =>
          <button onClick={onClick}>
            Upload Certificate...
          </button>
        }
      </UploadButton>
    );
}
```

As far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly.  But VSCode complains about the HTML in the function's `return` statement, and the app won't build.  I've never in the past encountered a problem with exporting HTML from a component.

Why is it giving me this error?  Am I missing a library?

Comment: 1. That isn't HTML, it's JSX. 2. Did you give the file the `.tsx` file extension? You can't have JSX in a Typescript file with the `.ts` file extension.

Comment: it can only return a single element. you are returning 2 - h1 and UploadButton (children inside don't count). Wrap it inside a fragment and it will solve your issues like `<> <h1> ... </h1> <UploadButton> ... </UploadButton> </>`

Comment: @Lith that fixed the problem (in addition to renaming the extension to .tsx).  But now I get a new error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`.  It doesn't like that I'm using `import * as fs from 'fs';`.  Running `npm install` didn't work.  Why would node/react/next.js complain about importing such a ubiquitous file IO library?

Comment: `fs` package is from nodejs. and its only used on the server side. hence you can not use it as a client (browser) does not have it

Comment: can also read up more on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application

Comment: Thanks @Lith I am reading the stackoverflow entry you linked and am trying to get it to work.  It's quite involved!  You would think that next.js would provide a simple "out of the box" way to read files in a server-side .tsx component (one that didn't involve changes to config/etc. files), given that this is such a common task in web development.

Comment: hmh... I had done few nextjs projects in life, worked for almost 2 years with it - I have never had it to read any text file... If I have a static/hardcoded json file - I just import it. If dynamic data - using database or API. not sure what project would need reading a literal file... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return to single element, you can modify in this way

```
return (<>
         <h1>Certificate Management</h1>
         <UploadButton uploader={uploader}
                  options={options}
                  onComplete={files => alert(files.map(x => 
                  fs.readFileSync(x.fileUrl, 'utf-8')).join("\n"))}>
           {({onClick}) => <button onClick={onClick}>
                           Upload Certificate...
                         </button>}
         </UploadButton>
      </>
    );
```