# Nextjs14 Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

fist of all I know similar questions like this were asked before but I tried a number of the different solutions provided and none of them worked for example this one, probably the most common solution [Stakoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64926174/module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-next-js-application).

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

I get this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/argon2/argon2.js
./db/firebase.js
./components/DashboardUI.jsx
./app/(admin)/dashboard/page.js
```

firebase.js

```
import { doc, addDoc, getDoc, getDocs, collection, where, query } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from "./firebase-config";



const argon2 = require('argon2');



export const checkPasswordMatch = async ({ pw }) => {

  const docRef = doc(db, "password", "password");
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);


  if (docSnap.exists()) {
    console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
    const hash = docSnap.data()

    try {
      if (await argon2.verify(hash, pw)) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return err
    }

  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
    return false
  }


}
```